# What does "Non procul abest" mean?

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In chapter 8 of Lingua Latina per se illustrata we have:

> Non procul abest.

What does this mean?
I understand every word but not really the sentence.

If it was "non procul est" I would understand "he/she/it is not far away" but "abest" (to be absent I think) really confuses me.

Comment: It is often followed by *quin* with a quasi-consecutive meaning: https://i.imgur.com/OZAMse5.png E.g. *Non procul afuit quin urbem caperent*:  it was not far off that they captured the city = they almost captured the city.

Answer (score 12):

Here is one way to make sense of this:
Think of *esse* as "to be" and *abesse* as "to be away".
Then *non procul est* is "he is not far" and *non procul abest* is "he is not far away".

The unprefixed version *non procul est* makes a statement about the location only, and the prefix *ab-* adds a tone of being away, out of reach, unavailable.

The phrasing of the translation makes a difference.
It makes sense to say that *non procul est* is "he is not far" and *non abest* is "he is not absent", but translating *non procul abest* as "he is not absent far" strikes me as nonsensical.
This is just a restriction of what combinations sound natural in English.

Perhaps this is a good illustration of why I think it is best to split a translation from Latin to English in two steps:
(1) Understand what the Latin means.
(2) Express that meaning in English.
The first step is wholly within Latin, the second one wholly within English.

I analyzed the phrase you quote as a whole sentence.
If it is a part of something bigger, the translation can look very different.
This underlines the point of the previous paragraph.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that _nōn_ modifies _procul_ and **not** _abest_, therefore the meaning would be "he's away, (but) not far (from here)"?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Yes, that is a good way to see it.